# Is CharSequence.length() always the same as String.length()?

Tags: java, android

Like the title says. Is the following statement guaranteed to be always true?

```
CharSequence x;
String       y;

y = x.toString();

if (x.length() == y.length()) // will this ALWAYS be true? (e.g. unicode, MLP, etc)
```

Comment: CharSequence is an interface.

Comment: One could implement a CharSequence that would normalize the text, and then it could violate equality of lengths. For normal usages the lengths are equal, String is based on a char array.

Comment: For a correct `CharSequence` implemention, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method declaration in [`CharSequence.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString--) mention the answer :

> String toString​()
>
> Returns a string containing the characters in this sequence in the
>   same order as this sequence. **The length of the string will be the
>   length of this sequence**.

So the returned `String` have the same `length` of the `CharSequence` if the implementation is correctly done.

**Of course, if the implementation is not fully based on the interface contract. This isn't true but that would not be a valid implementation of `CharSequence` either...** but this can't be guaranteed for every API.

---

Imagine the same thing with a `List` that always return a size of 5 no matter the number of element added... it doesn't make sense either because the `Collection` interface says :

> int size()
>
> Returns the number of elements in this collection.

---

IMO, Java is based on interface and documentation, if you can't trust either, you can't trust the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be guaranted for a single reason: `CharSequence` is an `interface`. It doesn't have implementation of `length()` method, only it's declaration. So anybody can implement it the way he wants. So I can make a class `MyCharSequence implements CharSequence` and implement `length` method to `return 10` always

Answer (score 0):

CharSequence is an interface, String is implementation. If length is equal or not depends on the implementation of CharSequence. For most of them I would say it would make sense to be equal but you cannot count on it.